# Keyboard shortcut to extract local variable in JS/TS in Visual Studio Code

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

I am looking for a shortcut that is available in Eclipse and called "extract local variable". It will assign the return value of the selected function invocation to a variable:

[image]

Is something similar available in VSC for Javascript and Typescript?

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/refactoring#_extract-variable

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the "Refactor..." shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to extract the expression to a constant. Example:

```
function main(){
  return "foo".replace("o", "a")
}
```

Mark the expression `"foo".replace("o", "a")` or the whole line → "Extract to constant in enclosing scope", name it to `test` and the function will be refactored to the following:

```
function main(){
  const test = "foo".replace("o", "a")
  return test
}
```

There is also the "Quick Fix" command (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>) for fixes *and* refactorings.

---

If you want an extra shortcut just for this action, define it manually in keybindings.json ([docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/refactoring#_keybindings-for-code-actions)):

```
  {
    "key": "shift+ctrl+alt+r",
    "command": "editor.action.codeAction",
    "args": {
      "kind": "refactor.extract.constant"
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, that works fine. Do you know where I can find a list of the available refactorings?  If I want to find the "kind" for "Move to file". I found this documentation https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/refactoring but nothing else

Comment: I haven't found an exhaustive list of code actions in the docs. What you can do is: Go into your `keybindings.json`, add a new `"editor.action.codeAction"` entry and then for `kind`, VS Code offers autocomplete. By typing `"refactor."`, you can see all possible refactorings - one of them is `refactor.move.newFile`, which should be the one you seek.